# Where can I report copy/typo errors in the Stack Overflow UI?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, contact

While visiting the Stack Overflow help center, I found a typo/error. Where I can report the mistake?

For example:

[image: Tour banner]

In first block it shows +10 in thumbnail and +5 in description.

Comment: if this is not the right place please let me know where to ask for such question?

Comment: Can't you just correct it? Documentation is intended to be collaborative. But if you do want to raise it to the broader community, right now the place to discuss Documentation is [Meta.SO].

Comment: actually this is not in content developers can edit, it is in tour section so I am not sure if I can change in that.

Comment: It was already reported by me in [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344275/2451726) :)

Comment: Yeah, That's great.
Thank you for informing :-)

Comment: Could this question be made on-topic of it were rephrased as "where can I report typo errors in a site's help center?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can post about these issues here, or on the Meta for the site in question. In this case, that would be Meta Stack Overflow.

It would likely be best to check a couple other sites. If they have the same error, feel free to post it here! Just be sure to check first to ensure the error hasn't already been reported.

If the error is only on one site, or you don't want to take the time to check other sites, post on that site's Meta. The team sees posts from all Meta sites, so they'll see it either way. However, most questions that affect just one site will be closed if posted here, on the main Meta.

Comment: You could also use the contact form on the bottom of the page.